# How to check SSH credentials are working or not

Tags: ssh

I have a large number of devices around 300 
I have different creds to them 
SSH CREDS, API CREDS 
So as I cannot manually SSH to all those devices and check the creds are working or not 
I am thinking of writing a script and pass the device IP's to the script and which gives me as yes as a result if the SSH creds are working and NO if not working.
I am new to all this stuff! details will be appreciated! 
I will run this script on a server from where I can ssh to all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear as to what sort of credentials you use for connecting to each host: do all hosts have the same connection method, for instance?

Let's assume that you use ssh's authorised keys method to log in to each host (i.e. you have a public key on each host within the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file).  You can run ssh with a do nothing command against each host and look at the exit code to see if the connection was successful.

```
HOST=1.2.3.4
ssh -i /path/to/my/private.key user@${HOST} true > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0]; then echo "Error, could not connect to ${HOST}"; fi
```

Now it's just a case of wrapping this in some form of loop where you cycle through each host (and choose the right key for each host, perhaps you could name each private key after the name or IP address of the target host).  The script will go out all those hosts for which a connection was not possible.  Note that this script assumes that `true` is available on the target host, otherwise you could use `ls` or similar.  We pipe all output to `/dev/null/` as we're only interested in the ability to connect.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO OP CLARIFICATION:

I'd strongly recommend not using username/password for login, as the username and password will likely be held in your script somewhere, or even in your shell history, if you run the command from the command line.  If you must do this, then you could use `expect` or `sshpass`, as detailed here: https://srvfail.com/how-to-provide-ssh-password-inside-a-script-or-oneliner/

The ssh command shown does not spawn a shell, it literally logs in to the remote server, executes the command `true` (or `ls`, etc), then exits.  You can use the return code (`$?` in bash) to check whether the command executed correctly.  My example shows it printing out an error message for non-zero return codes, but to print out `YES` on successful connection, you could do this:

```
if [ $? -eq 0]; then echo "${HOST}: YES"; fi
```

Comment: Sorry I am using a username and password.

Comment: To add it so we should be able to test the credentials and if it successfull it should display YES and kill the connection to the host so that the connection is not left there